# Rendering swf files in html with/Without swfobject

Tags: flash, swfobject, html

Without including swfobject.js can only swf files be loaded through html.And if so is there a common tag for all the browsers.

```
<object id="myMovieName" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
<param value="movie.swf" name="movie">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
<embed align=""
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       name="myMovieName"
       bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
       quality="high"
       src="movie.swf"
       href="movie.swf">
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination you posted, `<object>` with nested `<embed>` should work for all browsers. There isn't one tag that works for all browsers. See [this document](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) for details.

I would still recommend swfobject, though.

Comment: actually, you can use SWFObject's static publishing method, which doesn't require JavaScript. It uses nested object elements. See http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/static-publishing/

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation uses "smarty," which doesn't take {} especially during the variable declaration, this way is the only way.